# Execute click event in load form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple windows form with `_load` event

```
 private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //Code there
        }
```

and I have a button click event in the same form like

```
  private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //Code there
        }
```

I want to know how can I execute click event in load form. Regards

Comment: Have you tried just calling the method, maybe like `btnGenerate_Click(null, null)` (or `btnGenerate_Click(sender, e)`? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply call `btnGenerate_Click(sender, e);` from the `load` event, but the more idiomatic way is that both events call a separate method:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething() { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it the Button object:

I am doing it with my submit button like this:

```
// calling it inline, where Submit is the object/button (see HTML below for declaring it)
btnSubmit_Click(Submit, null);


// button submit call
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


<asp:Button ID="Submit" Text="Submit" runat = "server" onClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: Ok, I gave that as example, but you should be able to use the same logic but use the winforms button ID/Name